# Mean Survival Time Cox Regression

Tags: spss, survival

I am new at using survival analyses. I am writing an article on differences in recidivism for an experimental and control group of offenders. Due to differences between the groups in gender, I have added gender as covariate to my Cox Regression analysis. In Kaplan Meier, I get the mean survival time (no median, I think because in one of the groups the hazard ratio does not reach $0.50$), but this analysis does not take the covariate into consideration. Is it possible to request the mean survival time in Cox Regression using SPSS, for the analysis including the covariate?

Comment: One solution is to run Kaplan Meier on men and women separately.

Comment: If you can't estimate the 50th percentile of the survival time, then estimate the 25th for example. Or more than one single percentile. I strongly suggest you to take a look at the Laplace Regression, which can model percentiles of the survival times while adjusting for covariates. http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/bimj.200900310/abstract